# LinkedIn sharing URL does not show og:image

Tags: html, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with `og:image` on sharing post within LinkedIn sharing URL. Here is [test post](http://www.hsmanage.com/coil-post/) with configured `og` tags.

LinkedIn takes other `og:tags`, but not `og:image`.

I've checked page with the W3 validator. There are some errors, but they seem not really important. I've checked other page with working LinkedIn sharing and there are also similar html errors.

Also have tried to use cropped image, using shchemeless URL ([like in this article](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)), add `og:prefix` to HTML.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

[post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect) can help...

(1) in my LinkedIn profile, on 'Edit Intro' Under Media 
(Add or link to external documents, photos, sites, videos, and presentations.) I had added my website but the og:image wasn't being picked... even though I had already followed the advise as per the link in your question but image wasn't being displayed

(2) So after adding `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` in my html tag and changing the "https" to 'http' for my website I tried again, but no luck, even though the Post Inspector was picking it up

(3) I removed the media (from my profile intro) and saved. then added the same website address again and it worked like a charm. This could be because the image was being pulled from the cache (and since it wasn't there, i was getting a blank)... but when i added the media again, it did a fresh pull, which was successfull

Hoping someone else who experienced this issue will be helped with this...

Answer (score 1):

I found your are not including `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` in your root **HTML**
And your og:image size is not appropriate for universal social media sharing. Its better you give 1600:800 img (2:1) aspect ratio. And the file size below **1mb**.

Here is the link of [how to give og:images for universal social media](http://blog.rackspace.com/image-size-specs-across-social-media)

I hope this answer would help you.

Thanks